# How to make a dotted neon border?

Tags: css, frontend

I've made a neon border https://jsfiddle.net/cf3cec6c/

```css
    body{background:black;}
    h1 {
        color: white;
    }
    .wrapper{
    position: reltive;
     z-index: 999;             
        border:1px solid red;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
       
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
      border: 3px solid #0cd808;
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px #b3ff51, 0 0 2px #b3ff51, 0 0 6px #b3ff51, 0 0 12px #b3ff51, inset 0 0 1px #b3ff51, inset 0 0 2px #b3ff51, inset 0 0 6px #b3ff51, inset 0 0 12px #b3ff51;
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1> hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        <br>
         hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        <br>
         hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
        hello hello hello hello
      </h1>
    </div>
```

How can I make it a dotted one something like this:
[image: image of a motel/club sign with a thick red border with white, circular lights spaced inside of it]

Comment: You might want to check out [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) if you're trying to do something very complicated.

Comment: This can help you: http://codepen.io/luclemo/pen/xbMdEx

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the [`border-style: dotted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) style to your `.wrapper` class :

```
.wrapper{
    /* omitted for brevity */
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

This may not provide you with exactly the style you are looking for, but keep in mind that if you want to handle some complex border styles, you may be better off using the [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) style instead. You can even [use an online generator like the one seen here](http://border-image.com) to give you an idea of what your border will look like.

If you didn't mind adding quite a bit of HTML and didn't want to use the `border-image` approach, you could implement something like this :

```
<div class='border-outer'>
   <div class='border-inner'>
      <div class='content'>
          This is a test
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<style type='text/css'>
    .border-outer {
        outline: 5px solid red
    }
    .border-inner {
        background: red;
        border: 5px dotted #fff;
    }
    .content {
       background: #000; 
       color: #FFF;
       height: 80px;
       padding: 10px;
       border: 5px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

which can be seen in [this example](http://jsbin.com/vizana/edit?html,css,output) and would render something like the following :

[image]

It's by no means perfect or even elegant, but it somewhat resembles your targeted image. You might be better off using an example like [this one](http://hellohill.com/blog/neon-sign-in-pure-css/) that heavily relies on CSS but generates a really nice neon effect (sans the dots) :

[image]

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It gives black dots instead of converting the whole border into dots

Comment: It sounds like you are going to be better of using the `border-image` style as my edit suggests. I'd recommend using a generator like [this one](http://border-image.com) that will allow you to get the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but do you know of any other way than border-image? Any changes that i can make to wrapper to get the desired result?

Comment: I've edited my response with two examples. One that relies on a bit of additional HTML to build borders around a particular element and another example that will give you a true "neon" effect and although it lacks the dots, it's probably going to be close to your desired effect without resorting to the use of `border-image`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 6px dotted #0cd808;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way i can think of is by using a border image ( i believe someone mentioned that in a previous answer ), you will have to tweak image to your liking but this may be the best approach. here is a example:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/akKZqkx.png) 27;
-webkit-border-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/akKZqkx.png) 27;
-o-border-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/akKZqkx.png) 27;
border-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/akKZqkx.png) 27 fill;
```

you can see the border in action below:

http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FakKZqkx.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B27%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22round%22%2C%22round%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Afalse%7D

here is dotted version:
http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FWJEmP3v.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B27%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22repeat%22%2C%22repeat%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D